# Php - Bulk post 500 Apache Internal Server Error

Tags: php, apache

I've a script which send just a lot of data in json format
by post.

Up to about 10Mb (data are put into a flat file) of data the script works great but
if the load is higher I get from apache 500 Internal Server Error.

I peeped into apache log file I get

```
[Wed Jan 19 17:26:41 2011] [error] [client ip] Premature end of script headers: index.php
[Wed Jan 19 17:26:41 2011] [debug] mod_deflate.c(615): [client ip] Zlib: Compressed 632 to 385 : URL /index.php
```

Do you have any idea about it ?

Bye.

Comment: Did you check post_max_size in php.ini?

Comment: Yeah it's set to 100MB (post data is less)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Premature end of script headers

This message means the PHP script died before outputing any content-type to apache. If you have ob_* functions activated it could be any error on your PHP script, or a timeout, check your [set-time-limit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) parameter in PHP for timeouts.

Check as well that your exception handling output the correct content type if you want to output an error message.

To check all parameters that can have an impact you must check the timeout parameters and the size limits ones. Here are some of them:

Apache:

- LimitRequestBody

PHP:

- post_max_size
- upload_max_filesize
- max_input_time
- max_execution_time
- and maybe memory_limit as well

Comment: My current setting:
Apache
LimitRequestBody 0

php.ini
post_max_size = 500M
upload_max_filesize = 5M
max_input_time = 3600
max_execution_time = 3600
memory_limit = 128M

script
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set("memory_limit", "1536M");

but it doesn't work yet.

Comment: Try to have you php logs in a file (or in apache.log) and increase log level in PHP. can you catch some errors in PHP?

Comment: so I worked it out enable php log on syslog catching PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 38126284 bytes) in Unknown on line 0 and raising up  memory_limit to 256 in php.ini. I don't understand why on earth ini_set("memory_limit", "1536M"); didn't work :) Thanks for your help buddies :)

Comment: PS The server have got only 1024MB ram so may be ini_set("memory_limit", "1536M"); didn't work

Comment: check why your script needs to read in memory the whole file... I hope you do not have a magic_quote_gpc running for example; And now you must do something to prevent heavy memory usage in your script, check the Zend_memory component in Zend Framework library, maybe you can use it to swap things.