# Close Apache connection with too large file uploads

Tags: php, apache, upload, connection

I am currently working on a website where users can upload files. How can I prevent large files to be uploaded? At the time, no option (PHP’s `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize`) has been useful: the file is uploaded entirely. I would simply like the connection to be closed with too large files (by checking `Content-Length` HTTP header beforehand, and by checking while the file is being uploaded). Is there an Apache directive, or a PHP configuration key for this?

Thank you for your time!

EDIT: added [Apache conf](http://paste.awesom.eu/Iso/1rZ) (CentOS default).
EDIT2: added [PHP conf](http://paste.awesom.eu/Iso/1tc) (CentOS default) as well.

EDIT3: It seems that PHP closes the pipe when given a too large file. Nevertheless, Apache still allows transfer til it ends.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738691/php-bulk-post-500-apache-internal-server-error/4739476#4739476 , check parameters of that answer

Comment: We tried all of these except for the time-related ones: we do not want to be dependant of connection’s speed. Anyway, PHP seems not to be the issue, it is rather Apache’s.

Comment: As stated in the link and in @PhpMyCoder answer you have LimitRequestBody in Apache settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok.

So the main problem you are facing is that Apache directive **LimitRequestBody** or **LimitXMLRequestBody** are applied after the completion of the upload. Seems like apache is waiting for a complete file in a temporary folder before checking is size.

So you need to cut-down the connection right after the detection of too big uploads. One upon a time mod_throttle was a module available to do that. Checking this [Alternative to mod_throttle servfault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/30149/alternative-to-mod-throttle) you can have a list of bandwith control modules that may fit your needs.

[mod_bwshare](http://www.topology.org/src/bwshare/README.html) for example is able to limit bandwith per client IP, but that's not a per-request per_IP limit. There is also [mod_quos](http://opensource.adnovum.ch/mod_qos/), handling a lot of limitations on download things, but I can't find a lot of things for upload managment (only closing early slow upload maybe). See also [this answer on throttling uploads](https://serverfault.com/questions/52122/throttle-file-uploads-using-apache-2).

So you may also check for **OS level** limitation (on the TCP stack) or **advanced firewall** capabilities (ask on servfault).

You can also use client side limitation tools, like hidden form values or js uploader settings, but like anything used client-side, in term of security you cannot avoid someone altering the client-side limitations.

Answer (score 2):

You can use apache's [`LimitRequestBody`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody). Syntax is simple (and in bytes):

```
LimitRequestBody 10490000 # 10 MB
```

This works in both `httpd.conf` and `.htaccess`, just be mindful to restart if you edit `httpd.conf` (`sudo service apache2 restart` on Ubuntu).

If you need to set restrictions on a per file basis (limit avatar upload to 5 MB, but limit attachments to 20 MB), you can use [`<Files>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#files):

```
<Files avatarUpload.php>
    LimitRequestBody 5242880 # 5 MB
</Files>

<Files attachmentUpload.php>
    LimitRequestBody 20971520 # 20 MB
</Files>
```

Comment: We tested this as well; sadly the file is fully uploaded and Apache drops the connection afterwards.

Comment: Really? Then you should log a bug report with Apache - this explicitly contradicts what this functionality is intended to do (i.e. I am very dubious of your methodology)